# How to find the standard deviation of values in a file using awk to parse 500 files at once?

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, scripting, macos

I have 500 files each with a column of values I need to find the standard deviations for. I've figured out this much:

```
awk '{sum+=$5; array[NR]=$5} END {for(x=1;x<=NR;x++){sumsq+=((array[x]-(sum/NR))**2);}print sqrt(sumsq/NR)}' SL9_700.00001.bt
```

But I don't know how to replicate this for all SL9_700.0* files at once.

Comment: You do not have to retain any data to calculate standard deviation. You need a couple of variables to accumulate the sum of the values, the sum of their squares and their count. Your program need not contain any array or `for` loop at all.

Comment: Awk will process records from multiple files: `awk 'script' SL9_700.0*`.  `NR` will be the total number of records across all the files. The count of records in just the current file is `FNR`.

Comment: About standard deviation, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Identities_and_mathematical_properties  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Rapid_calculation_methods

Answer (score 0):

If your script does what you want for 1 file then with GNU awk for ENDFILE you can just tweak it to use ENDFILE instead of END and FNR instead of NR and reset your variables after using them for each file:

```
awk '{sum+=$5; array[FNR]=$5} ENDFILE {for(x=1;x<=FNR;x++){sumsq+=((array[x]-(sum/FNR))**2);}print sqrt(sumsq/FNR); sum=sumsq=0}' SL9_700.0*
```

or more legibly:

```
awk '
    {
        sum += $5
        array[FNR] = $5
    }

    ENDFILE {
        for (x = 1; x <= FNR; x++) {
            sumsq += ((array[x] - (sum / FNR)) ^ 2)
        }
        print sqrt(sumsq / FNR)
        sum = sumsq = 0
    }
' SL9_700.0*
```

You might want to add a test for FNR being 0 in the ENDFILE section and do something in that case to avoid getting a divide by zero error for an empty input file (that's true for NR in the END section in your original script too), e.g.:

```
awk '
    {
        sum += $5
        array[FNR] = $5
    }

    ENDFILE {
        if ( FNR == 0 ) {
            print 0
        }
        else {
            for (x = 1; x <= FNR; x++) {
                sumsq += ((array[x] - (sum / FNR)) ^ 2)
            }
            print sqrt(sumsq / FNR)
            sum = sumsq = 0
        }
    }
' SL9_700.0*
```

If you want the file name printed before each output value then change each `print` to `print FILENAME,`

Comment: I've tried your edited code, but nothing happens. No error but also nothing is printed.

Comment: Then you copy/pasted it incorrectly or you're not providing any input to it because those `print`s in the ENDFILE section mean it is utterly impossible for that script to run on any input and produce no output, and that includes if you ran it on an empty file when it'd output 0.

Comment: ``` awk '{sum+=$5; array[FNR]=$5} ENDFILE {for(x=1;x<=FNR;x++){sumsq+=((array[x]-(sum/FNR))**2);}print sqrt(sumsq/FNR); sum=sumsq=0}' SL9_700.0* ``` that's it, exactly how it's pasted in my terminal. I'm very confused as to why nothing whatsoever is happening

Comment: Type `awk --version`. I bet you're not using GNU awk as I said in my answer is required.

Comment: I checked that. GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: That version is 12 years out of date and missing a ton of useful functionality (including ENDFILE) and bug fixes, you should upgrade to the current version 5.1.0.